# Why my HikariCP springboot throw this exception?

Tags: java, jdbc, hikaricp

this is my sapplication.yml

```
spring:
```

datasource:
   type: com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
    primary:

```
  serverName: localhost
  portNumber: 3306
  databaseName: ccoee
  username: root
  password:  root
  dataSourceClassName: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
secondary:
  serverName: localhost
  portNumber: 3306
  databaseName: ccoee
  username: root
  password:  root
  dataSourceClassName: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
```

this is my starter:

```
ApplicationContext applicationContext = SpringApplication.run(
            TransqlApplication.class, args);
    DataSource dataSource = applicationContext.getBean(DataSource.class);
    System.out.println("datasource is :" + dataSource);
    //检查数据库是否是hikar数据库连接池
    if (!(dataSource instanceof HikariDataSource)) {
        System.err.println(" Wrong datasource type :"
                + dataSource.getClass().getCanonicalName());
        System.exit(-1);
    }
    try {
        Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection();
        ResultSet rs = connection.createStatement()
                .executeQuery("SELECT  1");
        if (rs.first()) {

            System.out.println("Connection OK!");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Something is wrong");
        }
        // connection.close();
        // System.exit(0);

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("FAILED");
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(-2);
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
```

and this my exception:

```
datasource is :HikariDataSource (null)
```

2017-11-21 10:10:33.126Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassCastException: Cannot cast com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver to javax.sql.DataSource
  INFO  at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.UtilityElf.createInstance(UtilityElf.java:93)
676 --- at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.initializeDataSource(PoolBase.java:338)
 [           main]  at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.(PoolBase.java:117)
com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource          at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.(HikariPool.java:109)
:   at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:97)
 HikariPool-1 - Starting...
    at com.mycjj.transql.TransqlApplication.main(TransqlApplication.java:51)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: Cannot cast com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver to javax.sql.DataSource
    at java.lang.Class.cast(Class.java:3369)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.UtilityElf.createInstance(UtilityElf.java:82)
    ... 5 more
2017-11-21 10:10:34.204 ERROR 676 --- [pool-1-thread-1] com.mycjj.transql.GetSql                 : 数据库连接异常,请检查地址/账号/密码是否正确

Answer (score 1):

A JDBC driver class is not a `javax.sql.DataSource`. You shouldn't be using the `dataSourceClassName` property, use the `driverClassName` property.

Also, `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver` is the class name of a development version of MySQL Connector/J 6.0 (which has been abandoned) or 8.0 (which is still in development). It is - at this time - not a released version, and you should not use it in production.